# Storing cookies in spring web app

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, datatable

I have a spring web application that uses a jquery data table just like the example on this page. 
https://datatables.net/
When the user selects the amount of entries they would like to view I want to be able to store that value in a cookie and default to that when they visit the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datatable's save state feature. Initialize your datatable with:

```
"bStateSave": true
```

PS.
This is not related to spring MVC - backend technology is irrelevant here.